# checking whether the variable is true or not

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

```
 function add(){
        <%if(empRecNum != null && !(empRecNum.equals("")))
    {
       empSelected=true;
    }
    boolean canModify = UTIL.hasSecurity("PFTMODFY") && empSelected;

     %>
    df('ADD');        

    }
```

When i click on add, i need to check whether the empSelected is true or not and pass this canModify value. Will this be called?

Is this right way i am checking a Scriptlet inside a JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `canModify` value defined in JSP is never passed to JavaScript. You need to redefine the variable in JavaScript, for example:

```
<%
if (canModify) {  // This is the JSP variable
%>
  var canModify = true;  // This is the JavaScript variable
<%
} else {
%>
  var canModify = false;
<%
}
%>
```

On a different note, you should abandon JSP scriptlets and switch to JSTL.

Comment: If the canModify is true, then i need to execute this JSP statement UTIL.hasSecurity("PFTMODFY") && canModify;

Comment: @John: Am I missing something? The code you posted is different from what you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Yes... if the canModify is true can i execute any JSP statements

Comment: @John: Yes you can, but they will be executed on the server-side and *only once*, so if you expect it to execute whenever the JavaScript `add` function is called, it won't work that way.

Answer (score 4):

A more elagant way to do this

```
var canModify = Boolean(${canModify});
```

Use jstl el, it turns more clear what do you intend to do.
The call to boolean will convert the given value in javascript boolean.

Remember:

```
Boolean(true); // returns true
Boolean(false); // return false
Boolean(); // returns false
```

Comment: This will only work if "canModify" is an attribute in the page or request scope. The way it's defined in the original question, this will not work.

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the following concept right: Java/JSP runs at webserver and produces HTML/CSS/JS output. Webserver sends HTML/CSS/JS output to webbrowser. Webbrowser retrieves HTML/CSS/JS output and displays HTML, applies CSS and executes JS. If Java/JSP has done its job right, you should not see any line of Java/JSP code in webbrowser. Rightclick page in webbrowser and choose *View Source*. Do you see it, right?

The webbrowser has totally no notion about the Java/JSP code on the server side. All it knows about and can see is the HTML/CSS/JS code it has retrieved. The only communication way between webbrowser and webserver is using HTTP requests. In the webbrowser, a HTTP request can be fired by entering URL in address bar, clicking a (bookmark) link, pressing a submit button or executing `XMLHttpRequest` using JavaScript. In the webserver, the Java/JSP (and Servlet) code can be configured so that it executes on certain URL's only. E.g. a JSP page on a certain location, a Servlet which is mapped on a certain `url-pattern`, etcetera.

In a nutshell, to have JavaScript to access Java/JSP variables, all you need is to let Java/JSP **print them as if** it is a JavaScript variable. To have JavaScript to execute Java/JSP methods, all you need is to let JavaScript **fire a HTTP request**.

See also: [Communication between Java/JSP/JSF and JavaScript](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html)